# Two same https websites on two different IP's

Tags: tls

Can I have the same https website (for example https://www.example.com/) hosted on two different IPs?

Comment: Yes. What is your actual question?

Comment: Yes you can, but you need a reverse proxy/load balancer.

Comment: Also, welcome to [security.se]. Your question is not about a security problem, but rather server configuration, so I voted to move it to [SF].

Comment: Is there any OCSP restriction for that, if I am not using reverse proxy and just set a two A records in my DNS and pointed www.example.com on two differenr IP's?

Comment: Yes you can, and you DON'T need a reverse proxy/load balancer.

Answer (score 3):

All what matters is that the certificate matches the hostname from the URL and that the certificate is valid and trusted. It does not matter if you have multiple IP address for the same hostname and use the same certificate on all of these. Such setup is actually very common for larger sites.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Do not forget to use rel canonical to avoid content duplication in search engines.

Comment: Eh? That would only be an issue they had different names.

Comment: Indeed. The most common mistake appears when one uses IP1 on https/site1.com and IP2 on https//www.site1.com

Comment: But the question was about instances using the vhost name. rel canonical is irrelevant.